# 1988 chevy k1500 350

Tags: engine, chevrolet, power

I have a chevy that has a loss of power and stalling.

About a week ago I drove it and it would spin the tires over, but the next day it wouldn't. it could be bad gas the truck was in the shop for about 6months getting the tranny fixed and I put gas from a gas can in their that could of been sitting outside

Most of the time it will crank on the second try, and will idle fine not sure on rpms gonna get a tachometer thursday I think it is idling a little high.

I'm going to change the fuel filter tomorrow or the next day but I don't think its been changed in awhile because the bolts on it are pretty rusty. I've replaced wires/plugs.

UPDATE1 1/27: I drove it to the store this morning got some gas, ran fine. Got home and (3-5 minute drive) let it sit for a sec cranked it up to check some stuff out and it was idling very rough (if I didn't give it gas it would die). So I checked both fuel injectors one is spraying fully and one just wasn't spraying. I took out the Injector fuse and ecm fuse put them back in then checked again and both were spraying, also did a little tapping on the injector that wasn't working.

UPDATE2 1/27:This evening I drove it to town and work which is probably in total about 20 miles most of the time is seemed fine but I noticed the first time I got down on it the CEL came on. Gonna try to check the codes myself tomorrow. It would spin the tires over but still seemed to have a lack of acceleration. So my question is what could be causing my injector to randomly not work? This is the first time i've actually seen it not spraying because its the first time i looked while the sputtering/dying without giving it  gas was happening I will see if it does it tomorrow and update if it does. going to change the fuel filter tomorrow and go from there.

Comment: Check back when you have some fresh fuel in it - that's the easiest thing to rule out.  **If it's carbuereted**, put a little bit of *good* fuel directly in the carb.  If the problem goes away for lil bit, you just have bad fuel.

Comment: "when I press on my brake fully when I release it my engine will rev up very slightly".  This is completely normal.  You have vacuum boosted brakes, and the vacuum is generated in the intake manifold.  When you press the brakes, you give a boost of air to the engine from your brake booster diaphragm.  This makes the engine rev.

Comment: Austin I have submitted the request to the team to merge your accounts. Once that happens you will have ownership of this post again

Comment: Austin still working on getting your account merged. In the mean time you can continue to use your registered account and if you need to make an edit someone will approve it.

Comment: Austin you will need to use the contact us link at the bottom of the page to get you accounts merged. They took away the ability for the mods to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Both injectors should be spraying the same amount on that system. Confirm your fuel pressure is correct if so then you need an injector. It's possible it's the wiring to that injector but not likely. You can confirm that by swapping the wires going to the two injectors. If the problem stays on the same injector then it's that injector for sure.